# Meaning of following syntax of cuda Kernel

Tags: visual-c++, cuda, opencl

What is meaning of following syntax:

```
Kernel_fun<<<256, 128, 2056>>>(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Which value indicates workgroup and which value indicates thread.

Comment: This is explained very clearly  in the first few pages of the CUDA  programming guide

Answer (score 14):

From the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration), appendix B.22 (as of May 2019):

> The execution configuration is specified by inserting an expression of
> the form  <<< Dg, Db, Ns, S >>> between the function name and the
> parenthesized  argument list, where:
>
> - Dg is of type dim3 (see Section B.3.2) and specifies the dimension and size of  the grid, such that Dg.x * Dg.y * Dg.z equals the number
>   of blocks being  launched; Dg.z must be equal to 1 for devices of
>   compute capability 1.x;
> - Db is of type dim3 (see Section B.3.2) and specifies the dimension and size of  each block, such that Db.x * Db.y * Db.z equals the
>   number of threads  per block;
> - Ns is of type size_t and specifies the number of bytes in shared memory that  is dynamically allocated per block for this call in
>   addition to the statically  allocated memory; this dynamically
>   allocated memory is used by any of the variables declared as an
>   external array as mentioned in Section B.2.3; Ns is an  optional
>   argument which defaults to 0;
> - S is of type cudaStream_t and specifies the associated stream; S is an  optional argument which defaults to 0.

In short:
`<<< number of blocks, number of threads, dynamic memory per block, associated stream >>>`

Comment: Thanks for giving response it's very use full information for me.

Comment: In the newest CUDA Programming Guide for Cuda6.5, it's actually in appendix B.19